# How to export 'usages' to file in intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I clicked <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>in IDEA and got a result.
I want to save this result in file.
Is it possible?

P.S.
I use idea 13 community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are in context menu exists correspond button
[image]